# Removing infrequent rows in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, frequency

Let's say I have a following very simple data frame:

```
a <- rep(5,30)
b <- rep(4,80)
d <- rep(7,55)

df <- data.frame(Column = c(a,b,d))
```

What would be the most ***generic*** way for removing all rows with the value that appear less then 60 times?

I know you could say "in this case it's just a", but in my real data there are many more frequencies, so I wouldn't want to specify them one by one.

I was thinking of writing a loop such that if length() of an 'i' is smaller than 60, these rows will be deleted, but perhaps you have other ideas. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any reason to keep these as separate rows instead of collapsing to one row per value (with a "count" column)?

Comment: Good point but, indeed, I need my data aggregated in this way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution using `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(Column) %>%
  filter(n() >= 60)
```

Or a solution from base R

```
uniqueID <- unique(df$Column)
targetID <- sapply(split(df, df$Column), function(x) nrow(x) >= 60)

df2 <- df[df$Column %in% uniqueID[targetID], , drop = FALSE]
```

Comment: Is there a way to apply this to multiple columns at once?

Comment: @MehmetYildirim It is possible, but we need a reproducible example to work on. Perhaps you can post a new question with a reproducible example so others can help you. I may take a look if you do that.

Answer (score 4):

We create a frequency `table` and then `subset` the rows based on the 'count' of values in 'Column'

```
tbl <- table(df$Column) >=60
subset(df, Column %in% names(tbl)[tbl])
```

Or with `ave` from `base R`

```
df[with(df, ave(Column, Column, FUN = length)>=60),]
```

---

Or we use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[.N >= 60], Column]
```

Or another option with `data.table` is `.I`

```
setDT(df)[df[, .I[.N >=60], Column]$V1]
```

---

If there are more than one column to group, place it in a `list` (or compactly `.(`)

```
setDT(df)[df[, .I[.N >=60], by = .(Column1, Column2)]$V1]
```

If there are many columns, we can also pass as a character string or object

```
colnms <- paste0("Column", 1:5)
setDT(df)[df[, .I[.N >=60], by = c(colnms)]$V1]
```

Comment: Is there a way to apply this to multiple columns at once?

Comment: @MehmetYildirim If you are talking about `Column`, then the by can be `.(Column1, Column2)]`

Comment: That works like a magic. You may write this an answer so others may see.

Comment: This code chunk `setDT(df)[df[, .I[.N >=60], by = c(colnms)]$V1]` removes the infrequent rows based on all included columns. I needed to double check which column to add. Rather that, I need to remove the infrequent rows based on each individual column, not the columns' combination. Kind of putting in a `for` loop or using `apply` function. I just want to put more columns to be on the safe side.

Comment: @MehmetYildirim please ask as a new question

Answer (score 3):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[Column %in% df[, .N, by = Column][N >= 60, Column]]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a variant to [Eric Watt's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46282676/3817004) answer which uses a join instead of `%in%`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[df[, .N, by = Column][N >= 60, .(Column)], on = "Column"]
```