# Remove infrequent rows for the count of values in EACH column

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have data with several infrequent levels in each column. Find the `dput()` of a small portion of data at the bottom of the question. Here's how the data is structured;

```
   AppointmentMonth DayofWeek AppointmentHour   EncounterType
1               Sep       Mon              16    Office Visit
2               Jun       Tue              13    Office Visit
3               Sep       Mon              14 Procedure Visit
4               Dec       Thu              14    Office Visit
5               Mar       Tue              11    Office Visit
6               May       Fri              14    Office Visit
7               May       Tue              11    Office Visit
8               May       Tue               9    Office Visit
.......
```

When you check the frequency table of each column you will realize some levels have 0, 1, or 2 occurrences. Here is an example.

```
table(data$AppointmentHour)
8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 
4  4  2  4  1  2  8  1  3  1
```

I would like to identify and remove the infrequent levels whose frequencies, let's say less than 3 (can be changed depending on the problem/data), in each column.

I tried @akrun's answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46282359/removing-infrequent-rows-in-a-data-frame/46282408?noredirect=1#comment131205274_46282408). Here is the code chunk:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(data)[data[, .I[.N >= 3], 
      by = .(AppointmentMonth, DayofWeek, AppointmentHour, EncounterType)]$V1]
```

However, this code removes the infrequent levels based on the combination of columns, not based on each individual column.

##### Data:

```
data <- structure(list(AppointmentMonth = structure(c(9L, 6L, 9L, 12L, 
3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 10L, 9L, 12L, 7L, 3L, 11L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 
12L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 12L, 1L, 3L, 11L, 4L, 9L, 4L), levels = c("Jan", 
"Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", 
"Nov", "Dec"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), DayofWeek = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 
2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 5L), levels = c("Sun", 
"Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), AppointmentHour = c(16L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 11L, 14L, 
11L, 9L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 10L, 16L, 15L, 8L, 8L, 11L, 8L, 14L, 8L, 
16L, 9L, 14L, 14L, 13L, 9L, 10L, 14L, 17L, 14L), EncounterType = structure(c(`Office Visit` = 1L, 
`Office Visit` = 1L, `Procedure Visit` = 2L, `Office Visit` = 1L, 
`Office Visit` = 1L, `Office Visit` = 1L, `Office Visit` = 1L, 
`Office Visit` = 1L, `Office Visit` = 1L, Appointment = 3L, `Office Visit` = 1L, 
`Office Visit` = 1L, `Office Visit` = 1L, `Office Visit` = 1L, 
`Office Visit` = 1L, `Office Visit` = 1L, `Office Visit` = 1L, 
`Procedure Visit` = 2L, `Office Visit` = 1L, `Office Visit` = 1L, 
`Office Visit` = 1L, `Office Visit` = 1L, `Office Visit` = 1L, 
`Procedure Visit` = 2L, `Office Visit` = 1L, `Office Visit` = 1L, 
`Office Visit` = 1L, `Office Visit` = 1L, `Office Visit` = 1L, 
`Office Visit` = 1L), levels = c("Office Visit", "Procedure Visit", 
"Appointment", "Treatment", "Telemedicine"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
30L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Using your filter of `>= 3` per column, that would wipe out all but `Jul`, `Sep`, and `Dec` (losing over half of your rows), is that your intent?

Comment: It would also wipe out five of your `AppointmentHour` levels, a third of your data. Those two columns alone reduce your 30 rows above to 12 rows of data. This gets worse, though, since now that you reduce those _rows_ based on values in each _column_, you have now 1 `Month`, 3 `DayofWeek`, and 3 more `Hour` levels that are `< 3`, meaning more reduction. What is the purpose of reducing a full row based on a low-count level in a column?

Comment: @r2evans `>= 3` is just an example. It can be 1 or 2, too. As I said in the question, this is just a fraction of the data. The problem arises when I apply logistics regression with k-fold cross-validation and if a column has levels with 1 or 2 occurrences. Therefore, I need to eliminate infrequent levels. The original data has more than 13,000 rows and the elimination of 20-30 rows won't affect the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Update:

We can use `inner_join` after filtering out rows based on each column:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
library(purrr)
```

```
map(names(data), ~ data %>% 
                    add_count(!!sym(.x)) %>% 
                    filter(n >=3) %>% 
                    select(-n)) %>% 
  reduce(inner_join, by = names(data))
```

```
#> # A tibble: 18 x 4
#>    AppointmentMonth DayofWeek AppointmentHour EncounterType  
#>    <ord>            <ord>               <int> <fct>          
#>  1 Sep              Mon                    16 Office Visit   
#>  2 Sep              Mon                    14 Procedure Visit
#>  3 Dec              Thu                    14 Office Visit   
#>  4 Mar              Tue                    11 Office Visit   
#>  5 May              Fri                    14 Office Visit   
#>  6 May              Tue                    11 Office Visit   
#>  7 May              Tue                     9 Office Visit   
#>  8 Jul              Tue                     9 Office Visit   
#>  9 Jul              Mon                    16 Office Visit   
#> 10 Nov              Mon                     8 Office Visit   
#> 11 Sep              Thu                     8 Office Visit   
#> 12 Nov              Tue                    11 Office Visit   
#> 13 Dec              Mon                     8 Procedure Visit
#> 14 Dec              Wed                    14 Office Visit   
#> 15 Jul              Tue                     8 Office Visit   
#> 16 Jul              Fri                    14 Office Visit   
#> 17 Dec              Thu                    14 Procedure Visit
#> 18 Mar              Mon                     9 Office Visit
```

##### Original Answer:

```r
col.tally <- function(dat, col) {
  temp <- paste0(col, "_count")
  dat %>% 
    group_by(!!col) %>% 
    mutate(!!temp := n()) %>% 
    ungroup()
}


map(names(data), ~col.tally(data, sym(.x))) %>% 
  reduce(left_join, by = names(data)) %>% 
  filter(across(contains("_count"), ~.x >= 3)) %>% 
  select(names(data))
```

Comment: You might need to edit the updated code so it can be computationally less expensive. I tried on my original data, but it took too much time to run. Instead, I check the infrequent levels with a set of variables and it works much better. My suggestion is to replace `.x = names(data)` with `.x = var_names` where `var_names = c("AppointmentHour", "VisitType", "EncounterType")`. So, the code can work better.

Comment: @MehmetYildirim I am not following. So you don't wanna run this on every column, but just the 3 columns you mentioned above?!

Comment: @ M-- I just want to emphasize that when I checked it for all columns, it took too much time. Instead of all columns, using a set of columns will speed up the code.

Comment: @MehmetYildirim that makes sense. Less computation, equals faster. You need to change it for your actual use case; however, in your question you've mentioned all columns. That's why I've used `names(data)`. Hope it solved your problem at the end.